# How does one find the GCD of three numbers with large exponent values?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

I have a problem which is to find the GCD of three numbers, each of which have large exponents:

$$ GCD( 2^{300}, 3^{200}, 2^{200})$$

What I have tried:

So far, I think there are two main steps here: (1) address the fact that its three numbers, and (2) attempt to get the GCD given the exponents. So first, I believe I can use Euclids algorithm:
[image]

Now, I would be working with only two values (which is what we have practiced so far). Now, I would have:

$$ GCD( 3^{200}, 2^{300})$$

What I am getting stuck is on the following step, and how to proceed, assuming this first step is correct. What I am inclined to do based on what we practice so far is to find the primes they have in common, but where I get stuck is how to do that for exponents, when searching for the GCD.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: how about $GCD( 3^{2}, 2^{3})\;$? - - - it is simpler, but not all that different.

Comment: Hint. Does $3$ divide any power of  $2$? Does $2$ divide any power of $3$? What is the gcd of $27$ and $64$?

Comment: Hint: What are the prime factorizations of these numbers?  This should be *easy*.

Comment: The only factors those have in common is 1?

Comment: Also note that the gcd of $2^{200}$ and $2^{300}$ is $2^{200}$ (the number with the SMALLER exponent) , although this does not affect the final result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the prime factorisation of the numbers, there is a more efficient way to find the GCD than Euclid's algorithm - remember that if $d$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$, that means that $a = md$ and $b = nd$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. But because of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, that means that the prime factors of $d$ must also be prime factors of $a$ and $b$, so it can only have prime factors that appear in both.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).